# Which method signature is good and why?

Tags: java

Given an IP Address Range ( a.b.c.d - a.b.c.e)  i would like a method to return the ip address's in an array list between the range.

Option 1 :

```
public static int getIPAddressesFromRange(String rangeStr, List list ) ;
```

return value  is `count`  and the input list would be populated with list of IP's the range has

Option 2:

```
public static List getIPAddressesFromRange(String rangeStr)
```

return value is the list of ip addresses'

My Option is 2, but that is intuition, not able to support my argument though.

Edit:  Is there any design principle the option 1 is violation ?

Comment: Try to write the calling code. That should lead you to option 2.

Comment: Never mind the design principles- option 1 imposes a functionality limitation that *cannot be fixed* due to the nature of the language, so you have issues with correctness even before you can think about the design.

Answer (score 5):

I'd say

```
public static List<String> getIPAddressesFromRange(String rangeStr)
```

if you decide to represent IP addresses as strings.

Arguments against #1:

- The caller needs to construct the list in advance
- It is not straightforward what the return value is unless you document it
- The method mutates one of its arguments, which is not in general forbidden, but it is best to avoid surprising the user of your API (especially if they are prone not to read the documentation)
- Passing in a `null` value accidentally for the list parameter will result in a NullPointerException.
- You can always get the length of the list from the list itself if you really care about it.

Comment: Also, even if the method were written defensively, it would be impossible to turn a null List into a non-null across a function call, so the first option literally has a subset of the second option's potential functionality. Worse, this is imposed solely by the design, not at all by the problem domain.

Answer (score 2):

Prefer the option 2 to the option 1.

The list contains its count anyway, so there is no need to return two values (the count and the list).

Also, since you know the type of the list, you can use generics: `List<String>`.

Finally, you might also consider taking two arguments: the beginning and the end of the range.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to return count in first method? You can fetch the number of IP's from List itself.

Second method should be the preferred one

Answer (score 2):

Your second option is best because the first option has two problems:

1. It's redundant. If a `List` is returned, you can use its `size()` method to get that count, so you gain nothing by returning the count.
2. The list must be validated and in some cases the method outright cannot perform its work. If the caller passes null, there is danger of a `NullPointerException` being thrown if the code was not written carefully. Also in that case, reassigning the parameter to point to a new list will not be observed by the caller, so your only remotely sane option is to throw a clear exception. With the second option, you have full control of the list until it is returned to the caller.

Answer (score 1):

Option two is probably better, since it is clear for any reader what is the method returning.

Method 1 might cause future coders to spend time thinking what is this parameter (unless it is properly documented), while method 2 is realy straight forward.

Option two also makes it more neat if you later need to iterate on the retrieved list, no need for temporary variables:

```
for (Object o : getIPAddressesFromRange(String rangeStr)) { ... }
```

You should also prefer using the [generic type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) `List<>` and not the raw type.

Answer (score 1):

Stuff in, stuff out. That's what your Option 2 does.

Option 1 mutates its input argument and returns redundant value (count, which can be got from the list).

Another thing is, perhaps a range of IP addresses would be described better by some other type than a String.

Answer (score 1):

IMO method signature suggests it will return a list of ip addresses from range, not how many addresses are in this range, hence I'm also for option 2.

Answer (score 1):

I think the 2nd one is better :

- The count is the size of the list
- You don't have to give a list to the function
- Less null pointer exception risk

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition is mine also, it is better to let getIPAddressesFromRange use its preferred implementation of List and avoid someone to give you an already populated list.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is that the second method signature is generally the best one as the first one will exposes your list object to concurrent modification. Thus, at the end of your method, it may hold less, more, other objects than expected.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you want to fill pre-created lists, or create new ones.

For example: You could do multiple calls to your function using the same List object to save some memory.

Or: To compare multiple lists, you may want to return a new List for each call.

I would go with Option 2.